# why isn't html form post data getting correctly parsed in node.js app?

Tags: html, node.js, parsing, web-applications, user-input

I am making a blog as a learning exercise - see [github project](https://github.com/gamma235/node-blog) - from scratch in node.js. I have an html form that looks like this with `input` and a `textarea` fields. On submit, each is supposed to be parsed as `title` and `content`, respectively.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Post Form
        </title>
        <link href="/css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            New post
        </h1>

        <form method="post" action="/posts" id="new_post" class="new_post">

            <div class="field">
                <label for="post_title">Title</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="post_title" size="30" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="post_content">Content</label><br>
                <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="20" id="post_content"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="actions">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Post" id="post_submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <p><br>
            <a href="/home">Back</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In an index.js file I have my routes defined and some utility functions to help me parse the data out of the submitted information.

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    qs = require('querystring');

// html file cache
var homeHTML = fs.readFileSync('views/post/home.html');
var newHTML = fs.readFileSync('views/post/new.html');
var postsHTML = fs.readFileSync('views/post/posts.html')


// render functions
...

function renderPostForm(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
  });
  response.end(newHTML);
}

function addNewPost(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
  });

  // the parseBody is defined below this function
  // title and content should get logged to the console, but title comes out Title: undefined
  // content works fine

  parseBody(request, function(body) {  
    var post = {
      title: body.title,
      content: body.content
    }
    console.log("Title: " + post.title);
    console.log("Content: " + post.content);
  });
  response.end(postsHTML);
}

// utils
...

function parseBody(request, callback) {
  var body = " ";

  request.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });
  request.on('end', function() {
    callback(qs.parse(body));  // I may be misunderstanding the usage of the parse function
  });
}

// routes
var homeREGEX = new RegExp('^/?$');
var newREGEX = new RegExp('^/posts/new/?$');
var postsREGEX = new RegExp('^/posts/?$');

// server
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

  if (homeREGEX.test(pathname)) {
    renderHome(request, response);
  } else if (newREGEX.test(pathname)) {
    renderPostForm(request, response);
  } else if (postsREGEX.test(pathname)) {
    addNewPost(request, response);
  } else {
    render404(request, response);
  }
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Where in your code do you think your form data should be parsed?  A post request is not sent as URL query string parameters.  Post data is sent in the body of the request and requires parsing from there.

Comment: well, I defined the `parseBody`function, which call the qs.parse function from the `querystring` module (imported at the top) on the body. It does this after all of the data is chunked in from the request. It gets called in the addNewPost function, that creates a new object called "post", populating it with `body.title` and `body.content`. Obviously, `body.content` is getting parsed with no problem. Why not `body.title`? So to answer your question, in the `addNewPost` function via the `parseBody` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting that it's because your `parseBody()` buffer is starting with a space and `title` is the first field in your form. So your buffer ends up being something like:

```
 title=foo&content=bar
```

instead of

```
title=foo&content=bar
```

Change `var body = " ";` to `var body = "";`.

Comment: This is the solution. I had just figured it out myself (pounds chest). Thanks!